# Displaying conditional Quantity Shopify

Tags: shopify, shopify-template

I am currently working on adding a quantity and the code works fine. 
The problem is for example

```
Product A has 3 variants
variant a = stock 100
variant b = stock 50
variant c = stock 0


{% if current_variant.inventory_quantity < 50 %}
<h4> <span id="inventoryQuantity">{{current_variant.inventory_quantity }}</span> available. </h4>    
{% endif %}
```

by creating the condition, it displays the info of all the stock however I would only like to display the stock that is less than 50. What happens now is the stock of 100 is showing even if my condition is less than 50.
Any idea? Thanks

Comment: Would you show us part of code defining current_variant ? Without this it's difficult to solve this.